# How can I add, correctly, this type of data?

Tags: python

This is the code, it's simple but I can't do the sum right!

```
import pandas

pd = pandas.read_csv('Estadistica ComplementarioEC3.csv')

cantidadDomicilio = pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 2']
cantidadDfe = pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 4']
cantidadBoleta = pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 6']

print(f'Cantidad domicilio: {cantidadDomicilio} ')
print(f'Cantidad DFE: {cantidadDfe}')
print(f'Cantidad Boleta: {cantidadBoleta}')

resultado = cantidadDomicilio + cantidadDfe + cantidadBoleta
print(resultado)
```

And this is the output

Cantidad domicilio: 2,995
Cantidad DFE: 2,887
Cantidad Boleta: 371
Resultado: 2,9952,887371

I don't know how it's done!

Comment: *"I don't know how it's done!"* - How ***what*** is done? What is your quesiton?

Comment: @Tomerikoo How can I add these values? Because it doesn't add well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstand your problem**, you need to cast your `string` to `integer` before doing the sum like this-

**Note**: the values of **cantidadDomicilio**, **cantidadDfe**, and **cantidadBoleta** are being treated as `strings` rather than `numbers`. This is causing them to be concatenated rather than added when you perform the `+` operation.

```
import pandas

pd = pandas.read_csv('Estadistica ComplementarioEC3.csv')

cantidadDomicilio = pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 2'].replace(',', '')
cantidadDfe = pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 4'].replace(',', '')
cantidadBoleta = pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 6'].replace(',', '')

print(f'Cantidad domicilio: {cantidadDomicilio} ')
print(f'Cantidad DFE: {cantidadDfe}')
print(f'Cantidad Boleta: {cantidadBoleta}')

resultado = cantidadDomicilio + cantidadDfe + cantidadBoleta
print(resultado)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas

pd = pandas.read_csv('Estadistica ComplementarioEC3.csv')


cantidadDfe = int(zip(pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 4'].split(',')))
cantidadDomicilio = int(zip(pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 2'].split(',')))
cantidadBoleta = int(zip(pd.loc[14,'Unnamed: 6'].split(',')))

print(f'Cantidad domicilio: {cantidadDomicilio} ')
print(f'Cantidad DFE: {cantidadDfe}')
print(f'Cantidad Boleta: {cantidadBoleta}')
resultado = (cantidadDomicilio) +(cantidadDfe) + (cantidadBoleta)
print(resultado)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ignacio.carrera\Desktop\Pedido nicole\resultado.py", line 14, in <module>
    resultado = int(cantidadDomicilio) + int(cantidadDfe) + int(cantidadBoleta)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,995'